# Auto layout visual programming language for an array of views

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

Let's say I have an array of views, and I want to stack these views in a list. Now, if I know ahead of time how many views there are, I could write a constraint like this:

```
"V:|-[view0]-[view1]-[view2]-[view_n]"
```

However, how can I accomplish something like this with a variable number of views in my array?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the array and build the string (use an `NSMutableString`). You need to add the views to a dictionary with keys that match the names you use in the format string.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this awesome category:

https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout

It has a spaceViews method that you can call on the container view and will space an array of views evenly along the specified axis.

There's some sample code in the demo project that should cover everything.

Here is how you would space some views evenly over the vertical axis:
This centre 4 views on the x axis and constrain the width to 150 points. The height would then be calculated depending on the height of `self.view`

```
#import "UIView+AutoLayout.h"

...

- (void)spaceViews
{
    NSArray *views = @[ [self spacedView], [self spacedView], [self spacedView], [self spacedView] ];

    [self.view spaceViews:views onAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical withSpacing:10 alignmentOptions:0];
}

- (UIView *)spacedView
{
    //Create an autolayout view
    UIView *view = [UIView autoLayoutView];

    //Set the backgroundColor
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    //Add the view to the superview
    [self.view addSubview:view];

    //Constrain the width and center on the x axis
    [view constrainToSize:CGSizeMake(150, 0)];
    [view centerInContainerOnAxis:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX];

    //Return the view
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Be sure to check out my fork of that project, which re-designs and cleans up the API and includes much more functionality (including many methods to constrain arrays of views): https://github.com/smileyborg/UIView-AutoLayout

Answer (score 0):

I had a requirement to add views from an array to a scrollview for my tutorial pages, in this case I built the VFL string by looping through the views, below is a snapshot, this code is to fit subview fully into scrollview's page. With some tweaks, padding,etc can be added. Anyways posting it here so that it helps someone.

Full code [arrayAutolayout](https://github.com/anoop4real/ScrollViewAutolayoutViewsFromArray)

```
/*!
 Create an array of views that we need to load
 @param nil
 @result creates array of views and adds it to scrollview
 */
-(void)setUpViews
{
    [viewsDict setObject:contentScrollView forKey:@"parent"];
    int count = 20;//Lets layout 20 views
    for (int i=0; i<=count; i++) {
        // I am loading the view from xib.
        ContentView *contenView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContentView" owner:self options:nil][0];
        contenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        // Layout the text and color
        [contenView layoutTheLabel];
        [contentScrollView addSubview:contenView];
        [viewsArray addObject:contenView];
    }
}
/*!
 Method to layout the childviews in the scrollview.
 @param nil
 @result layout the child views
 */
-(void)layoutViews
{
    NSMutableString *horizontalString = [NSMutableString string];
    // Keep the start of the horizontal constraint
    [horizontalString appendString:@"H:|"];
    for (int i=0; i<viewsArray.count; i++) {
        // Here I am providing the index of the array as the view name key in the dictionary
        [viewsDict setObject:viewsArray[i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%d",i]];
        // Since we are having only one view vertically, then we need to add the constraint now itself. Since we need to have fullscreen, we are giving height equal to the superview.
        NSString *verticalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|[%@(==parent)]|", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%d",i]];
        // add the constraint
        [contentScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:verticalString options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
        // Since we need to horizontally arrange, we construct a string, with all the views in array looped and here also we have fullwidth of superview.
        [horizontalString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@(==parent)]", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%d",i]]];
    }
    // Close the string with the parent
    [horizontalString appendString:@"|"];
    // apply the constraint
    [contentScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:horizontalString options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
}
```

Below is the string created

```
H:|[v0(==parent)][v1(==parent)][v2(==parent)][v3(==parent)][v4(==parent)][v5(==parent)][v6(==parent)][v7(==parent)][v8(==parent)][v9(==parent)][v10(==parent)][v11(==parent)][v12(==parent)][v13(==parent)][v14(==parent)][v15(==parent)][v16(==parent)][v17(==parent)][v18(==parent)][v19(==parent)][v20(==parent)]|
```